# Attempts to transfer ETH from my Ether.li wallet appear OK, but the ETH never arrives at the destination

Tags: ether, ether.li

I've tried many times to transfer my ETH from my **Ether.li** wallet to another wallet and everything appears good, but nothing actually happens. The latest transaction says:

```
Withdrawal request - 97 ETH to 0xf7a1b79bfc55f2cfc315599ea5428225f3548217 
Approved at 2/12/17 9:55 PM
```

Why?

Comment: Did you fund the user account with minimum 0.01 Ether? I had a problem with that. After funding 2FA was no problem today.

Answer (score 3):

https://etherscan.io/address/0xf7a1b79bfc55f2cfc315599ea5428225f3548217

The transaction isn't being broadcasted, even if EtherLi may be saying it's approved. I'm assuming you're doing all the correct MultiSig signing.

Comment: I'm doing the two-factor auth -- they text me a code and I enter it. How do I fix this? Is this a known issue with ether.li?

Comment: I haven't used Ether.li, but in other applications 2 factor and multi signature are two different security layers.